# STATUS_PAUSED won't call onReceive() in DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I used `DownloadManager` to download a file from server, I expect when the network is not connected to internet I receive `STATUS_PAUSED` in `BroadcastReceiver`. But it doesn't call `onReceive()`.

```
downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // ...
    }
}

registerReceiver(downloadReceiver,
    new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're filtering for the `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` action, your receiver will not receive any other broadcasts.

Moreover, `STATUS_PAUSED` is not a broadcast.

It's the status of a particular download managed by the `DownloadManager`, which you can query.

For example:

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();

query.setFilterById(idsToQuery);
query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED);

Cursor cursor = dm.query(query);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // do whatever you would like with the result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as [Download Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) class is concerned, it does not `Broadcast` any status regarding the state of the Downloading content. Only two statuses are broadcasted

1. ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE
2. ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED